# How do you loop through multiple google searches and scrape the first result?

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a boolean search in google, changing one aspect of the search using an f string. I'm new to Python and can't figure out how to loop over multiple queries using a list. I want to append the first google result to a variable and print that variable.

This is the code I have so far:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
companies = ['ABC', 'ACME', 'XYZ']

profile_links = []

search = f'https://www.google.com/search?q=%28%22jobtitle1%22+OR+%22jobtitle2%22+OR+%22jobtitle3%22+OR+%22jobtitle4%22%29+AND+%22{companies}%22+AND+%28Location1+OR+Location2+OR+Loction3%29'

r = s.get(search, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'})

for companies in search:
    profile = r.html.find('a', containing='linkedin')[0]
    if profile==True:
        profile.append(profile_links)
    else:
        break
    print(profile_links)
```

Comment: What result are you getting? Perhaps move your print statement outside your for loop.

Comment: Not quite sure what it is you're trying to do.  `profile_links` is the empty list and is never modified.

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank and Madison. If I get rid of the loop, I can display the linkedin profile link which is exactly what I want. What I can't do is loop through a list of queries to get links for different searches. The idea behind this is to find a certain kind of person within a company on Linkedin and then automate that search across X number of companies. In this case it will only be about 40 companies so I don't have to worry about using the Google API as I understand it.